# new to java - synchronized static methods lock on the class

Tags: java, android

the documentation states that synchronized static methods lock on the class, but i have no idea what that means. Can you explain that ?

```
public static synchronized Object getObjectById (Class objclass, Long id) {
```

Comment: Generall question about technology, demanding an explanation. Could easily be found anywhere else on the internet

Answer (score 1):

That means that any time you will access this method, it will be locked and no other thread will be able to access it until the lock is destroyed. In another words, the method content will never be executed at the same time by multiple threads.

Beware though as synchronization, by nature, slows down the application as threads may have to wait a bit to continue their execution

Comment: but what does STATIC syncrhonized mean... i do understand synchronzed

Comment: Static means "at a class level", i.e. you don't need an instance to access it. For example : `MyClass.myStaticMethod()` or `MyClass.MY_CLASS_ATTRIBUTE`

Answer (score 0):

Basically it means, that if you have static synchronized methods in class Foo, they cannot run simultaneously. If 2 threads will try to access them at the same time, one thread will get a lock. Other thread will have to wait.

Non-static synchronized methods use some object as a lock. static synchronized methods use class.

Foo a = new Foo();
Foo b = new Foo();

a.syncMethod() and b.syncMethod() can run simultaneously, because they lock on different objects.

Foo.staticSyncMethod() and Foo.anotherStaticSyncMethod() **cannot** run simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

Assume you have two static methods and both are defined as synchronized. Both **cannot** execute concurrently as they share the same lock (which is the Class itself).

```
public static synchronized void Foo()

public static synchronized void Bar()
```

These two cannot run concurrently.

But they can execute concurrently with a non static synchronized method. The reason is non static synchronized methods lock on the actual instance that is running.

Good luck.